# Python Selenium Locating Element and Clicking on it

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait, linktext

I have been stuck in this line of code for over 2 weeks now, and I am hoping someone might come to my assistance!

I am using python selenium to navigate through a website which contains a database. I want to click on a link which will open a new tab, from which I am going to extract the information that I am looking for. I only need to do this once, so no need for any sort of loops! However, I have tried multiple times and I have been getting the `ElementClickInterceptedException` error message every time. I have tried using `WebDriverWait`, and then I get `NoSuchElement` error message. I've tried searching the element through several ways, including id, class name, `xpath`, and link text, but no luck!

The HTLM code looks like this:

```html
<a id="reportsForm:j_idt290:4:j_idt295" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget nav-item " onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('reportsForm',{'reportsForm:j_idt290:4:j_idt295':'reportsForm:j_idt290:4:j_idt295'}).submit('reportsForm','_blank');return false;" target="_blank"><span id="reportsForm:j_idt290:4:l2" data-hasqtip="reportsForm:j_idt290:4:tooltipID" aria-describedby="qtip-reportsForm:j_idt290:4:tooltipID">Análise Financeira e de Gestão</span></a>
  <span id="reportsForm:j_idt290:4:l2" data-hasqtip="reportsForm:j_idt290:4:tooltipID" aria-describedby="qtip-reportsForm:j_idt290:4:tooltipID">Análise Financeira e de Gestão</span>
```

So far, I have tried:

```
afg = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Análise Financeira e de Gestão") 

afg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Análise Financeira e de Gestão')]")

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"reportsForm:j_idt290:4:j_idt295"))).click()

afg = driver.find_element_by_id("j_idt290:4:j_idt295")
```

I think the problem might be because the link text is not immediately after the `href`, and not even in the same line! And so, when I search by link text, it can't be found...

Also, sometimes, without changing the code at all, just by running it again, with the driver.find_element_by_id method, it works out of nowhere once or twice, but then its stops working again!

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!!! :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: Just use Cypress...lol...jkjk

Comment: The webpage is only accessible through a user and password, so unfortunately, I cannot share!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath.

```
//a[normalize-space(.)="Análise Financeira e de Gestão"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I recieved this error message: 
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'trackOutboundLink(\'Relatório Sugerido Alerta\', \'Click\', \'...\', \'\', \'_blank\');','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'companyForm\'),{\'companyForm:tableLastUpdate:1:j_idt248\':\'companyForm:tableLastUpdate:1:j_idt248\'},\'_blank\')');return false">Análise Financeira e de Gestão</a> is not clickable at point (675, 701). Other element would receive the click: <div id="fundo">...</div>

Comment: Sounds like you might need to wait for the element to finish loading. Since I don't have the full HTML this is just a guess. You can try using a wait method to explicitly wait. Here is an example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element you're trying to hit is found within a frame, if that's the case you should switch to that iframe first and then you'll be able to perform the desired action on that element

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have just double-checked the whole HTML code, there doesn't seem to be several frames within the page...